# jQuery on click change toggle class on a div

Tags: jquery, html, css, class

I have 4 href's which when clicked on i need to change the class of a div.

For example:
- Click on link 1 = the div class will change to s1,
- Click on link 2 = the div class will change to s2,
- Click on link 3 = the div class will change to s3,

And so on, I have some code below, but not sure on the jQuery as im just learning it

http://jsfiddle.net/Nh7tn/1/

```
<div class="vehicleJourney">
    <div id="progress">
        <div id="complete" class="s2"><!--need class to change -->
            <div id="marker"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="buttons">
      <ul>
        <li class="s1"><a  class="showSingle" data-target="1">s1</a></li>
        <li class="s2"><a  class="showSingle selected" data-target="2">s2</a></li>
        <li class="s3"><a  class="showSingle" data-target="3">s3</a></li>
        <li class="s4"><a  class="showSingle" data-target="4">s4</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

</div>​
```

Cheers

Answer (score 3):

If you want to apply to the div the class in the text of the link, you may do this :

```
$('a.showSingle').click(function(){
   $('#complete').attr('class', $(this).text()); 
});
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/wuHrJ/)

If you want to apply to the div the class of the parent of the link, you may do this :

```
$('a.showSingle').click(function(){
   $('#complete').attr('class', $(this).parent().attr('class')); 
});
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/CTQBC/)

If you want to apply to the div a class computed from the number of the link, you may do this :

```
$('a.showSingle').click(function(){
   $('#complete').attr('class', 's'+($(this).parent().index()+1)); 
});
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/CTQBC/)

When you're in your real application (i.e. not in jsfiddle), the code should be embedded in a ready callback in a script at the end of your body :

```
<script>
    $(function(){
       $('a.showSingle').click(function(){
          $('#complete').attr('class', 's'+($(this).parent().index()+1)); 
       });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: cheers, the text within <a  class="showSingle" data-target="1">s1</a></li> reads something else, i just put that in there for demo purposes

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document)​.ready(function() {
    $('.showSingle').click(function() {
        $('#complete').attr('class', '').addClass('s' + $(this).data('target'));
    });
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

See the updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nh7tn/2/)

```
$('.showSingle').click(function(){$('#complete').attr('class',$(this).html());});
```

Answer (score 0):

That should work

```
$("li a").click(function(){
  var classname=$(this).text();
  $("#complete").attr("class",classname);
});
```